# Is there any difference in creating PFX file from SSL certificate directly from IIS Export and creating PFX file from MMC Export

Tags: iis, pfx, mmc

Just want to confirm is there any difference in creating pfx file from IIS Direct Export as below :

[image]

And creating pfx file from MMC as below :

[image]

Comment: Deep down they use the same Windows API, so the result is the same.

Comment: Yes, there is no difference.